# Split wireshark to miliseconds

Tags: time, wireshark, editcap

How to split wireshark files based on time interval. `Editcap` does not allow to split files in milliseconds? Can give only seconds using `editcap -i`.

Answer (score 2):

This will be supported in Wireshark 3.2.0, which is due to be released this fall. If you need the functionality sooner you can try one of the 3.1 [automated builds](https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/).

Comment: thanks. 'Time delta from previous displayed frame' value of each split file's first row/packet is zero. Even though the time delta of those packets in the original file is not zero. How to get the actual inter-arrival time of packets please?

Comment: Pcap and pcapng files only store the arrival time for each packet. The frame.time_delta and frame.time_delta_displayed fields are calculated based on the first packet in a file, i.e. those values aren't saved in the capture file. (Calculated values are denoted by wrapping them in square brackets, e.g. "[Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.025961000 seconds]").

You could probably work around the issue by extracting the first packet from the first file using editcap and prepending it to the rest of the files using mergecap.